# Sync Google Drive Desktop

Tags: hard-drive, google-drive

I changed my google password, and desktop no longer syncs.  I've seen some other posts that say to click on the google drive icon and 'quit', then log back in.  I can't find the quit option anywhere?

Comment: Just end the process through Task Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You can Quit the Google drive from the "Tray Icon" or Task Manager.

From the Tray Icon, right click the Google drive icon and choose "Quit Google Drive"

Or, Open the Task Manager and right click the "googledrivesync.exe"

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, the Google Drive icon should appear in your task bar on the right side - it might be hidden so you have to click the little up-arrow in the task bar to see it. Clicking it should show the "Quit Google Drive" option at the bottom of the pop-up menu.